# Floated elements inherit top margin when the containing element has a clear property

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

I've stumbled across a bug with floated elements within a container when that container uses `clear: both;` (or left/right). In Chrome (not Safari), the first floated element is positioned correctly, but all subsequent elements appear to inherit the top margin of the parent element, shifting them out of line.

Here's the problematic code: http://jsfiddle.net/peterjmag/3zJey/1/

Try the toggle link to see the difference. Also, try various values for `margin-top` on `#product-listing`.

For those of you using other browsers, here's what the fiddle looks like for me (in Chrome 25.0.1364.160 for Mac):

[image: JSFiddle output screenshot]

**Why does `clear: both;` cause this behavior in Chrome?** According to [the CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#flow-control), the `clear` property should only affect floated elements that appear earlier in the document, not within the targeted element.

(Of course, I know there are other more optimal ways to clear previous elements in the document which would not require a clear property on the container div—I'm simply trying to understand why this happens.)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't very... clear (ha). I was asking why `clear: both;` caused this behavior, when that property's only meant to affect elements that appear earlier in the document. However, I discovered just a few minutes after posting that it is indeed a browser bug (thus the edit). I'll clarify the question for future reference and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is indeed a Chrome bug: [Issue 178134: Floated elements render incorrectly when parent element has a clear property + a top margin](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178134). According to that report, Chrome 27 and above are not affected.